# Date Filter Between 2 dates and text

Tags: sql, vb.net

Good day

I am trying to filter my data from 2 dates and based from a text.
Here is my code for loading data on the datagridviewer.

```
Private Sub frmMCOUT_Load_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim publictable As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT DateEncoded as [Date Encoded], LOTNUMBER as [Lot Number], PARTSLIST as [Part Number - Part Name], prdInput as [Input], prdOutput as [Output], OPERATOR as [Operator], PROCESS as [Process], MACHINE as [Machine], REJECTS as [Reject], INTDATE as [Date], Shift as [Shift], PROCMONTH as [Year and Month], PARTNUMBER as [Part Number], PARTNAME as [Part Name], HELPERKEY as [Helper] from ProdOutput WHERE PROCESS = 'MACHINING'; "


    Try
        'open the connection
        'conn.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = sql
        End With
        'get the SQL statements used to select records in the datasource
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        'it fills the datatable
        da.Fill(publictable)
        'populate the datagridview
        dtgEntryList.DataSource = publictable
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally

        conn.Close()
        da.Dispose()
    End Try
    dtgEntryList.Sort(dtgEntryList.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)


End Sub
```

I have 2 date picker which I need to filter that has been entered between those 2 dates. I also need to filter the data so that it will show "Machining" process. Any Idea on how to this??

Thank you

Comment: So you need to write your `WHERE` clause to filter on those values and add the appropriate parameters to the command. Plenty of existing information and examples of that out there for you to follow. Let us know if you encounter an issue when you do that.

Comment: Do you want to filter in the DB or in VB?

Comment: in VB. I inserted in the data grid view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have separated the database code from the user interface code. this makes the code easier to maintain.

Don't declare connections outside of the method where they are used.

Use `Using...End Using` blocks to ensure that database objects are closed and disposed.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Private publictable As DataTable

Private Sub frmMCOUT_Load_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        publictable = GetPartsData()  
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = publictable
End Sub

Private Function GetPartsData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT DateEncoded as [Date Encoded], LOTNUMBER as [Lot Number], PARTSLIST as [Part Number - Part Name], prdInput as [Input], prdOutput as [Output], OPERATOR as [Operator], PROCESS as [Process], MACHINE as [Machine], REJECTS as [Reject], INTDATE as [Date], Shift as [Shift], PROCMONTH as [Year and Month], PARTNUMBER as [Part Number], PARTNAME as [Part Name], HELPERKEY as [Helper] from ProdOutput 
    WHERE PROCESS = 'MACHINING' 
    Order by LOTNUMBER DESC; "
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

After the user has a chance to pick the dates, filter the `DataTable` with the `Select` method and assign the resulting row array to the grid. I wasn't sure which date field you wanted to filter. Just change `Date Encoded` to the field you want. Use the name of the field present in the `DataTable` not the field name in the database.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim StartDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim EndDate = DateTimePicker2.Value
    Dim filteredData = publictable.Select($"Date Encoded >= {StartDate} And Date Encoded <= {EndDate}")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = filteredData
End Sub
```